# How can i import a map to MCPEDL?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

So i’ve been searching through a lot of videos and things to try find it but none of the files work it always shows empty or there is no ‘games’ folder in it, I’ve tried Mediafire, ES File manager and Files they dont work, Which file app should i use?

Comment: I am using iOS / iPad :

Comment: And what is the folder path you are trying to take to find your Minecraft files?

Answer (score 2):

If you’re on an iPad you should have a Files app that is by Apple and comes with the OS. Then go to the “On my Ipad” tab in the left and click the minecraft folder. Go to games>com.mojang>minecraftWorlds>TheWorldOfYourChoice and then click select and select every folder. Then click more on the bottom right and click compress. Then you are going to need some kind of app that changes names. Literally just go to the app store and search file manager. Then you must change the name to LiterallyAnyNameYouWant.mcworld . If its not .mcworld it won’t work. Then you can either upload the file to mediafire or directly to MCPEDL.

Answer (score 0):

1.To install Minecraft PE maps you need ASTRO File Manager (or any other file manager). Lets start by installing that app on your Android device.
2. Download the map you like.
3.Use ASTRO File Manager to open the .RAR or .ZIP and then copy the world folder to the following path: /storage/emulated/0/games/com.mojang/minecraftWorlds/. It might take a few seconds for it to process.
4.Open Minecraft Pocket Edition (or restart the app if you had it opened during the map installation).

Comment: Welcome to [gaming.se]! Please note that whenever you copy content from elsewhere, you need to [properly reference it](/help/referencing).